# Intellij scala compilation error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ 10 with scala plugin and sbt. I used the lift_archetype_basic from maven(as IntelliJ plugin) to create a basic lift webapp. If I use maven to compile the project, it works. However, IntelliJ seems to see errors everywhere in scala syntax. Apparently IntelliJ is not using scala compilation libraries, even though they are clearly mentioned in the Scala facet for the project. I have made sure that scala compile libraries are also mentioned as dependencies in Module settings. If I force compile a scala file, I get:

> javac: invalid flag: /home/dropfatdiva/lifttest/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala

Has anyone else seen this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the .scala extension is mapped to the correct file type in Settings | File Types.

(quoting [the answer from Dmitry Jemerov](http://ivan-gandhi.livejournal.com/1799614.html))